# C# Creating PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb skewing image

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapsource

I am trying to combine 3 grayscale bitmaps into one color bitmap.  All three grayscale images are the same size (this is based off of data from the Hubble).  My logic is:
Load "blue" image and convert to `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`.  Based off of that create a new byte array that is 4 times as large as the blue data array length/3 (so it will be one byte for blue, one byte for green, one byte for red, one byte for alpha per pixel since my system is little endian).  Populate the "blue" bytes of the array from the "blue" bytes of the blue image (and in this first loop set the alpha byte to 255).  I then load the green and red bitmaps, convert them to `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`, and pull the g/r value and add it to the correct place in the data array.  The final data array then has the bgra bytes set correctly from what I can tell.

When I have the data array populated, I have used it to:

Create a `PixelFormats.Bgra32 BitmapSource` then convert that to a Bitmap.

Create a `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` Bitmap using the Bitmap constructor (width, height, stride, PixelForma, IntPtr)

Create a `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` Bitmap using pointers

All three ways of creating a return bitmap result in the image being "skewed" (sorry, I don't know of a better word).

The actual output (of all three ways of generating the final bitmap) is: [Actual output](http://wierdling.longboys.net/soBitmap/output.png)

The desired output is something like (this was done in photoshop so it is slightly different): [Desired output](http://wierdling.longboys.net/soBitmap/desiredOutput.png)

The three file names (`_blueFileName, _greenFileName, _redFileName`) are set in the constructor and I check to make sure the files exist before creating the class.  I can post that code if anyone wants it.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I am guessing that is is due to the stride or something like that?

Note:  I can't post the links to the images I am using as input as I don't have 10 reputation points.  Maybe I could send the links via email or something if someone wants them as well.

Here is my code (with some stuff commented out, the comments describe what happens if each commented out block is used instead):

```
    public Bitmap Merge()
    {
        //  Load original "blue" bitmap.
        Bitmap tblueBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(_blueFileName);
        int width = tblueBitmap.Width;
        int height = tblueBitmap.Height;
        //  Convert to 24 bpp rgb (which is bgr on little endian machines)
        Bitmap blueBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(blueBitmap))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(tblueBitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
        }
        tblueBitmap.Dispose();
        //  Lock and copy to byte array.
        BitmapData blueData = blueBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, blueBitmap.Width, blueBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            blueBitmap.PixelFormat);
        int numbBytes = blueData.Stride*blueBitmap.Height;
        byte[] blueBytes = new byte[numbBytes];
        Marshal.Copy(blueData.Scan0, blueBytes, 0, numbBytes);
        blueBitmap.UnlockBits(blueData);
        blueData = null;
        blueBitmap.Dispose();
        int mult = 4;
        byte[] data = new byte[(numbBytes/3)*mult];
        int count = 0;
        //  Copy every third byte starting at 0 to the final data array (data).
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length / mult; i++)
        {
            //  Check for overflow
            if (blueBytes.Length <= count*3 + 2)
            {
                continue;
            }
            //  First pass, set Alpha channel.
            data[i * mult + 3] = 255;
            //  Set blue byte.
            data[i*mult] = blueBytes[count*3];
            count++;
        }
        //  Cleanup.
        blueBytes = null;
        int generation = GC.GetGeneration(this);
        GC.Collect(generation);

        Bitmap tgreenBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(_greenFileName);
        Bitmap greenBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(greenBitmap))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(tgreenBitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
        }
        tgreenBitmap.Dispose();
        BitmapData greenData = greenBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, greenBitmap.Width, greenBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            greenBitmap.PixelFormat);
        numbBytes = greenData.Stride * greenBitmap.Height;
        byte[] greenBytes = new byte[numbBytes];
        Marshal.Copy(greenData.Scan0, greenBytes, 0, numbBytes);
        greenBitmap.UnlockBits(greenData);
        greenData = null;
        greenBitmap.Dispose();
        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length / mult; i++)
        {
            if (greenBytes.Length <= count * 3 + 1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            //  Set green byte
            data[i * mult + 1] = greenBytes[count * 3 + 1];
            count++;
        }
        greenBytes = null;
        generation = GC.GetGeneration(this);
        GC.Collect(generation);

        Bitmap tredBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(_redFileName);
        Bitmap redBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(redBitmap))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(tredBitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
        }
        tredBitmap.Dispose();
        BitmapData redData = redBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, redBitmap.Width, redBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            redBitmap.PixelFormat);
        numbBytes = redData.Stride * redBitmap.Height;
        byte[] redBytes = new byte[numbBytes];
        Marshal.Copy(redData.Scan0, redBytes, 0, numbBytes);
        redBitmap.UnlockBits(redData);
        redData = null;
        redBitmap.Dispose();
        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length / mult; i++)
        {
            if (redBytes.Length <= count * 3+2)
            {
                count++;
                continue;
            }
            // set red byte
            data[i * mult + 2] = redBytes[count * 3 + 2];
            count++;
        }
        redBytes = null;
        generation = GC.GetGeneration(this);
        GC.Collect(generation);
        int stride = (width*32 + 7)/8;
        var bi = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, data, stride);
        //  uncomment out below to see what a bitmap source to bitmap does.  So far, it is exactly the same as 
        //  the uncommented out lines below.
        //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //return BitmapImage2Bitmap(bi);
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* p = data)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)p;
                //  Trying the commented out lines returns the same bitmap as the uncommented out lines.
                //  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                byte* p2 = (byte*)ptr;
                Bitmap retBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                BitmapData fData = retBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                unsafe
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fData.Height; i++)
                    {
                        byte* imgPtr = (byte*)(fData.Scan0 + (fData.Stride * i));
                        for (int x = 0; x < fData.Width; x++)
                        {
                            for (int ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++)
                            {
                                *imgPtr++ = *p2++;
                            }
                            //*imgPtr++ = 255;
                        }
                    }
                }
                retBitmap.UnlockBits(fData);
                //Bitmap retBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, GetStride(width, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb),
                //    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, ptr);
                return retBitmap;
            }
        }

    }

    private Bitmap BitmapImage2Bitmap(BitmapSource bitmapSrc)
    {
        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSrc));
            enc.Save(outStream);
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(outStream);
            return new Bitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    private int GetStride(int width, PixelFormat pxFormat)
    {
        int bitsPerPixel = ((int)pxFormat >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int validBitsPerLine = width * bitsPerPixel;
        int stride = ((validBitsPerLine + 31) / 32) * 4;
        return stride;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the gap between the lines. The `Stride` value is not the amount of data in a line, it's the distance between the start of one line to the next. There may be a gap at the end of each line to align the next line on an even address boundary.

The `Stride` value can even be negative, then the image is stored upside down in memory. To get the data without the gaps and to handle all cases you need to copy one line at a time:

```
BitmapData blueData = blueBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, blueBitmap.Width, blueBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, blueBitmap.PixelFormat);
int lineBytes = blueBitmap.Width * 3;
int numbBytes = lineBytes * blueBitmap.Height;
byte[] blueBytes = new byte[numbBytes];
for (int y = 0; y < blueBitmap.Height; y++) {
  Marshal.Copy(blueData.Scan0 + y * blueData.Stride, blueBytes, y * lineBytes, lineBytes);
}
blueBitmap.UnlockBits(blueData);
blueBitmap.Dispose();
```

Comment: Aligned to a multiple of 4, not "even".  Bitmaps are normally upside-down, stride is negative when the first scanline is at offset 0.

Comment: @HansPassant: An even address boundary is not the same as an "even address". Regarding the stride, you are mistaken. The stride is the offset from one scan line to the next, so when the bitmap is upside down the stride is negative. You add the stride to the address to get to the next scan line, you don't subtract it.

Comment: @Guffa thank you.  I was thinking the stride was the amount of data per line.  Knowing it is the full width of the line (data + padding to hit  the next even address boundary) really clears up a lot of things for me.